# Nginx балансировка поддоменов Apache

Tags: apache, nginx

Есть баллансировщик `nginx` и 2 сервера `Apache` за ним.
2 сервера привязаны к домену, так же на них настроены поддомены.

Если я выставляю конфиг без указания портов, то получаю на поддомене страницу с домена; если ставлю порты то ошибка `502 bad gateway`.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

`Dns` прописаны `А`, `@` и `*` записи.

```
upstream back1 {
ip_hash;
server 0.0.0.1;
server 0.0.0.2;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.site.ru;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://back1;
}
}
```

`

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
ServerName site1.site.ru
ServerAlias *.site.ru
DocumentRoot /var/www/site.ru/html/site1
ErrorLog /var/www/site.ru/site1/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/site.ru/site1/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
ServerName site2.site.ru
ServerAlias *.site.ru
DocumentRoot /var/www/site.ru/html/site2
ErrorLog /var/www/site.ru/site2/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/site.ru/site2/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `proxy_set_header Host $host;` в каждом первом примере

Comment: У вас сейчас запросы в апач уходят с хостом back1

Comment: спасибо, помогло